# Does VBA have something similar to LIKE in SQL? I'm looking to use the .Find method to find all cells where the text begins with "SQL_"

Tags: excel, vba

This is the code I have right now. It works and can find "SQL_" if the cell only contains that and nothing else. WHat I'd like to is have the .Find method search instead for cells that contain "SQL_" at the beginning and then the rest of the text looks like SQL_Database.dbo.tableName

```
'Find every cell that contains 'SQL'_..., then take string and store to 3 variables: Database Name, Schema Name, Table Name
Sub FindSQLName()

    For Each ws In TargetWB.Worksheets
        With ws.Range("A:Z")
            Set Rng = .Find("SQL_", LookIn:=xlValues)
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                sqlString = Rng.Value
                MsgBox sqlString
            Else
                MsgBox "Nothing found"
            End If
        End With
    Next ws
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Use a wildcard: `"SQL_*"` and `LookAt:=xlWhole`.

Comment: @BigBen the wildcard was the fix, however, the code works when using xlValues. Is that a big deal using xlValues vs xlWhole?

Comment: `xlValues` is unrelated to `xlWhole`. The former is for `LookIn` and the latter is for `LookAt`. If it was unclear, I was suggesting that you add `LookAt:=xlWhole`, while keeping `LookIn:=xlValues`.

Comment: @BigBen ahh okay thanks